# Let $ab=cd$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$. Then $a | d$ and $c | b$.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $ab=cd$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1$. Then $a | d$ and $c | b$.

$ab=cd \implies a|cd,$ but $\gcd(a,c)=1 \implies a \nmid c$, so $a | d$.

$ab=cd \implies c|ab,$ but $\gcd(a,c)=1 \implies c \nmid a$, so $c | b$.

Is the solution correct?

Comment: Be careful. Just knowing that $a \nmid c$ and $a \mid cd$ does not, in general, imply $a \mid d$.

Comment: why? @TheoBendit...

Comment: For example, $a = 6$, $c = 15$, and $d = 10$.

Comment: But here we have the gcd condition @TheoBendit

Comment: We do, but I feel that you haven't properly explained how this gcd condition has been used. The result is absolutely true when the gcd condition holds, but your answer seems to gloss over it. You're better off citing a result from class to justify this step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

$\gcd(a, c) = 1, \tag 1$

then there are $m, n \in \Bbb Z$ with

$ma + nc = 1; \tag 2$

so,

$mab + nbc = b; \tag 3$

now $ab = cd$ implies $c \mid ab$, whence $c \mid b$; likewise,

$mad + ncd = d, \tag 4$

and $ab = cd$ yields $a \mid cd$, so $a \mid d$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

The first implication is the consequence of the definition of divisibility

and second $a|cd$ and $\gcd(a,c)=1 \implies a|d $

is true because of Euclid lemma. Similarly for the second one.

For Euclid lemma: page 24 Elementary Number Theory 6th edition by David M. Burton

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma

Answer (score 0):

Considering the equation $ab=cd$ modulo $a$, we have $cd\equiv 0 \mod a$. Since $\gcd(a,c)=1$, $c$ is invertible modulo $a$, and thus $d\equiv 0 \mod a$. That is, $a\mid d$. We can similarly conclude that $c\mid b$ by considering $ab=cd$ modulo $c$.